# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and for any $x_1 \lt x_2 \in [a,b]: f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing on $[a,b]$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I want to prove the following visually intuitive claim:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and for any $x_1 \lt x_2 \in [a,b]: f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing on $[a,b]$.

There is a logical conclusion I made, marked by a $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$ that I *think* is correct, but I just wanted to make sure.

---

Suppose $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are three arbitrary elements in $[a,b]$ such that $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3$. To avoid contradicting the assumption, we must have either $f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$ or $f(x_1) \gt f(x_2)$. WLG, assume the first.

Similarly, to avoid contradicting the assumption, we must have either $f(x_2) \lt f(x_3)$ or $f(x_2) \gt f(x_3)$. Assume the latter: **we will show that this leads to contradiction**.

Finally, either $f(x_1) \lt f(x_3)$ or $f(x_1) \gt f(x_3)$. WLG assume the former.

So we have the following:

$f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$, $f(x_2) \gt f(x_3)$, and $f(x_1) \lt f(x_3)$.

Note, then, the following inequality: $f(x_1) \lt f(x_3) \lt f(x_3)+\frac{|f(x_2)-f(x_3)|}{2} \lt f(x_2)$

Because $f$ is continuous, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, we know that there exists an $x' \in [x_2,x_3]$ such that $f(x')=f(x_3)+|f(x_2)-f(x_3)|$. Similarly, we know that that there is an $x^* \in [x_1,x_2]$ such that $f(x^*)= f(x_3)+|f(x_2)-f(x_3)|$. Because $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3$, clearly $x' \neq x^*$, but $x',x^* \in [a,b]$ and $f(x')=f(x^*)$. A contradiction.

In conclusion, for any $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3 \in [a,b]$, we have that $f(x_1) \lt f(x_2) \lt f(x_3)$ or $f(x_1) \gt f(x_2) \gt f(x_3)$.

From this, we can derive that for any $x_1 \lt x_2 \in [a,b]$, we have $f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$ **OR** $f(x_1) \gt f(x_2)$ $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$. This is equivalent to saying that $f$ is strictly increasing or $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[a,b]$ $\quad \square$.

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: I was thinking about some function as $f(x) = x+w(x)$ with $w(x)$ the [Weierstrass function](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/weierstrass/weier.htm#:~:text=Here's%20a%20graph%20of%20the,can%20see%20it's%20pretty%20bumpy.), trying to found a continuous counterexample with $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2),\,\forall\, x_1 \neq x_2$ but without having $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ or $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$... but I don´t was able to figure it out if its fulfill $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2),\,\forall\, x_1 \neq x_2$, but maybe it could gives you an idea of where testing your hypothesis.